# What should be the interval for warmup script scheduled?

Tags: iis, application-pool, warm-up

There are lots of Sharepoint wake up/warm up script available. But what should be the scheduled interval? I think it is based on particular environment. It is my understanding:

1. Set IISReset at 4am and run warmup 2 minutes after. (ref: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2013/04/06/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes.aspx)
2. If number of visit is very low (close to zero), I will schedule to run every 15 minutes because application pool idle timeout is 20 min (MS default).
3. Some people said Sharepoint crawler will do the same thing as warmup script. However I doubt "incremental crawl" will visit every site collection. Also it may spend for hours to complete.

Am I understand the IIS + Sharepoint behaviour correctly?

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm not a big fan of warm up scripts, well for the start page and a few "hot" sites/pages it might be of interest. Remember that if you warm up all your sites/pages you will put a big memory pressure on the servers and to benefit from it you need to up the RAM. The important thing is to hit a few sites so the JIT is done for the assemblies and controls, not that all pages have cached data.
If you "warm up" to many pages the IIS/ASP.NET will eventually start to throw out old cached data from memory.

And you are correct, having crawl as a warm up thing is just plain stupid (excuse the word used). Exactly as you say incremental/continous crawl will only hit updated items. Secondly it will not load the page as the user sees it. Third you should NOT crawl your web servers, but instead dedicated crawl targets - which invalidates the whole thing anyways.

Comment: Wictor, how do you determine which page or site to warm up? This morning I boot up my VM, run the warmup script and find one community portal need 25s while the other site collections load up in 3s. Will it be a good indicator? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The warm up duration depends on your configuration,hardware and assembly counts and changes for every system .

There is a nice blog written about this by Bugrapostaci.

Below is the link for it :-
https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2012/11/30/why-we-are-using-warm-up-scripts/

Let me know for any concerns.